# Increment char in for loop

Tags: php

I would like to know how i can make something like this : 
Does a php function exists ?

```
for ($i=0; $i < 26; $i++) { 
    // echoes "A" ... b ... c ...
}
```

Comment: what output you need?

Comment: `$char = "A";
  for($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++) echo $char++;` ?!

Comment: @ Anand Somasekhar 

i would like to get the char in a var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP supports [Perl-style character incrementing](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

so simply use

```
for($char = 'A'; $char !== 'IW'; $char++) {
    echo $char, PHP_EOL;
}
```

which will print out from `A` to `IV`.... it is important to use a `!==` in the terminating comparison though

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)

```
foreach (range('a','z') as $char)
{
    // do something with $char
}
```

Comment: Or just print implode(range('a', 'z'));

Comment: that depends on what OP wants to do with it